# content parse with some exceptions in memory efficient manner

Tags: php, domdocument, simple-html-dom, domxpath, php-7.4

Below one is my sample data and what I tried using xpath. Here my aim is to modify all text in html by excluding `script, style` tags and few classes `noparse, generic`.

Here is link to my sample input and php script :

https://3v4l.org/urIBl#v7.4.21

can someone show some light towards right path ?

**My input:**

```
$html=<<<doc
<html>
<head>
<title>My page</title>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
   $('.ajax').trigger('change');
})
//]]></script>
<style>ul li ol li{color;red;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<ul>
    <li>Languages
        <ol>
        <li>PHP</li>
        <li class='noparse'>C++</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
<span>inline text</span>
<p class="generic">some long text data</p>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" title="resource hub">Stack Overflow</a>
<a href="https://google.nl" title="Google" class="inline-a noparse otherclass">Google</a>
<img class="img-responsive parse round red" src="" alt="round image" />
<img class="img-responsive noparse round red" src="" alt="square image" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
doc;
```

**This is what I tried**

```
<?php


libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_SCHEMA_CREATE);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$exclude='.generic,.noparse';

foreach ($xpath->query("//*/text()[not(@class='$exclude')]|//a/@title[not(@class='$exclude')]|//img/@alt[not(@class='$exclude')]")  as $node)
{ 
  $node->textContent=$node->textContent.' powered by sometext';
} 

echo $dom->saveHTML();

?>
```

**Expected results:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My page powered by sometext</title>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
   $('.ajax').trigger('change');
})
//]]></script>
<style>ul li ol li{color;red;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<ul>
    <li>Languages  powered by sometext
        <ol>
        <li>PHP  powered by sometext</li>
        <li class='noparse'>C++</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
<span>inline text  powered by sometext</span>
<p class="generic">some long text data</p>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" title="resource hub  powered by sometext">Stack Overflow  powered by sometext</a>
<a href="https://google.nl" title="Google" class="inline-a noparse otherclass">Google</a>
<img class="img-responsive parse round red" src="" alt="round image  powered by sometext" />
<img class="img-responsive noparse round red" src="" alt="square image" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is what I'm getting from script ( This is not desired output )**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
 powered by sometext<head>
 powered by sometext<title>My page powered by sometext</title>
 powered by sometext<script>
//<![CDATA[

$(function(){
   $('.ajax').trigger('change');
})
//]]> powered by sometext</script>
 powered by sometext<style>ul li ol li{color;red;} powered by sometext</style>
 powered by sometext</head>
 powered by sometext<body>
 powered by sometext<div>
 powered by sometext<ul>
     powered by sometext<li>Languages
         powered by sometext<ol>
         powered by sometext<li>PHP powered by sometext</li>
         powered by sometext<li class="noparse">C++ powered by sometext</li>
         powered by sometext</ol>
     powered by sometext</li>
 powered by sometext</ul>
 powered by sometext<span>inline text powered by sometext</span>
 powered by sometext<p class="generic">some long text data powered by sometext</p>
 powered by sometext<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" title>Stack Overflow powered by sometext</a>
 powered by sometext<a href="https://google.nl" title class="inline-a noparse otherclass">Google powered by sometext</a>
 powered by sometext<img class="img-responsive parse round red" src="" alt>
 powered by sometext<img class="img-responsive noparse round red" src="" alt>
 powered by sometext</div>
 powered by sometext</body>
 powered by sometext</html>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, First is html\php code snippet, second is expected output, third is actual output. Is any of this is input?

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear. Can you check now I just made an edit.

Comment: Besides the script problem, which I don’t have an answer for right now, you should also be checking if `$node->textContent` contains only whitespace and skipping that.

Comment: For the script, if this HTML is representative of your actual data, you could try targeting only descendants of `body`

Comment: you mean something like this `if ( strlen(trim($node->textContent)) )`

Comment: but how to exclude tags and classes

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

Here is edited script:

Notes:

1. You have following code. I am not sure what it is. I tried to search on net but I could not get any information. The parsing and therefore output goes wrong because of that syntax:

```html
  //<![CDATA[
  <script>
```

If you know what it is and cannot figure out how to fix parsing please reply.

2. I am not sure whether you want to change attributes as well or not. I see your expected output has some inconsistencies so I did not spend more time on fixing things about attributes: First `a href` does *not* have excluded classes but it's class attribute expected to change. While for `img` it does not.

```html
<a href="https://google.nl" title="Google" class="inline-a noparse otherclass">Google</a>
<img class="img-responsive parse round red" src="" alt="round image  powered by sometext" />
```

```php
<?php

  $html=<<<doc
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>My page</title>
  //<![CDATA[
  <script>
  $(function(){
     $('.ajax').trigger('change');
  })
  //]]></script>
  <style>ul li ol li{color;red;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
  <ul>
      <li>Languages
          <ol>
          <li>PHP</li>
          <li class='noparse'>C++</li>
          </ol>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <span>inline text</span>
  <p class="generic">some long text data</p>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" title="resource hub">Stack Overflow</a>
  <a href="https://google.nl" title="Google" class="inline-a noparse otherclass">Google</a>
  <img class="img-responsive parse round red" src="" alt="round image" />
  <img class="img-responsive noparse round red" src="" alt="square image" />
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
  doc;

  libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
  $dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_SCHEMA_CREATE);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

  $excluded_tags = array("script", "style");
  $excluded_classes=array('generic', 'noparse');

  $nodes = $xpath->query("//*");
  foreach ($nodes as $node)
  {
  
     if ($node && $node->nodeName) {
        if (!in_array($node->nodeName, $excluded_tags)) {
           if (0 < $node->childNodes->count() && "#text" === $node->childNodes[0]->nodeName) {
             if (!$node->hasAttribute('class') || !in_array($node->getAttribute('class'), $excluded_classes)) {
                $nodeValue = preg_replace('/\s+$/', '', $node->childNodes[0]->nodeValue);
                if (0 != strlen($nodeValue)) {
                  $node->childNodes[0]->nodeValue = $node->childNodes[0]->nodeValue.' powered by sometext';
                  //echo "Node Name: ", $node->nodeName, " Node Child Count: ", $node->childNodes->count(), " Node Child Name: ", $node->childNodes[0]->nodeName, " Node Child Value: ", preg_replace('/\s+$/', '', $node->childNodes[0]->nodeValue), PHP_EOL;
                  
                   if ($node->attributes) {
                      foreach ($node->attributes as $attribute) {
                        if ('href' != $attribute->nodeName) {
                           $attribute->nodeValue = $attribute->nodeValue.' powered by sometext';
                        }
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
           }
        }
     }
  } 

  echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

**Output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>My page powered by sometext</title></head><body><p>
//
$(function(){
   $('.ajax').trigger('change');
})
//]]&gt;
 powered by sometext<style>ul li ol li{color;red;}</style>

</p>
<div>
<ul>
    <li>Languages
         powered by sometext<ol>
        <li>PHP powered by sometext</li>
        <li class="noparse">C++</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
<span>inline text powered by sometext</span>
<p class="generic">some long text data</p>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" title="resource hub powered by sometext">Stack Overflow powered by sometext</a>
<a href="https://google.nl" title="Google powered by sometext" class="inline-a noparse otherclass powered by sometext">Google powered by sometext</a>
<img class="img-responsive parse round red" src="" alt="round image">
<img class="img-responsive noparse round red" src="" alt="square image">
</div>

</body></html>
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: sorry this is not giving correct output example check script tag is missing, noparse class should not be parsed/modified

Comment: Hi your solution does not work. Please check